# Open local file with click on a Button on Java form

Tags: java, forms, button, action

New to Java. Creating a button on a Java form and want button click to open a jnlp file located on a local drive.

How will that be possible? Double clicking on the button takes me

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}
```

Comment: what you tried before ask question here?

Answer (score 0):

The class to help you open files with the default program is called "Desktop". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html, especially `Desktop.open( File );`

Comment: Thanks Florian. Let me try that.